# System ID and Client Change in Manage System Alias

Tags: sap-fiori

I have implemented My Inbox app in S4hana 1610,since its odata service(taskprocessing) requires System ID and Client for Local GW and Local App.(As shown below)
[image: System Alias]

Since I won't be knowing Production Server's System ID and Client in advance,then the same will be reflected there,thereby creating issue.

Is there any way that system ID and Client auto-detected or any other workaround?

Regards,

Sayed

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually change the system alias in the Production system.

Comment: I won't be allowed to open Production Client to change System Alias.....is there any other workaround ?

Comment: Things which are landscape specific have to be changed in Prod/QA. Another example, RFC destination within the System Alias. Usually, you do not have to open the system to edit those.

Answer (score 0):

There has been a change in IMG functionality with SP06 of Netweaver Gateway 2.0.
[Here](https://blogs.sap.com/2013/05/31/how-to-maintain-sap-system-alias-entries-in-productive-systems/) it is described how to maintain SAP System Alias entries in productive systems.

Comment: From the blog,I can't see option "Display IMG Activity" under Edit.(Manage System Alias).

Comment: Is this still an issue?
Which SP release is your Netweaver Gateway?